# Assigning result of pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
date,       industry, symbol, roc
25-02-2015, Health,   abc,    200
25-02-2015, Health,   xyz,    150
25-02-2015, Mining,   tyr,    45
25-02-2015, Mining,   ujk,    70
26-02-2015, Health,   abc,    60
26-02-2015, Health,   xyz,    310
26-02-2015, Mining,   tyr,    65
26-02-2015, Mining,   ujk,    23
```

I need to determine the average 'roc', max 'roc', min 'roc' as well as how many symbols exist for each date+industry. In other words I need to groupby date and industry, and then determine various averages, max/min etc.

So far I am doing the following, which is working but seems to be very slow and inefficient:

```
sector_df = primary_df.groupby(['date', 'industry'], sort=True).mean()
tmp_max_df = primary_df.groupby(['date', 'industry'], sort=True).max()
tmp_min_df = primary_df.groupby(['date', 'industry'], sort=True).min()
tmp_count_df = primary_df.groupby(['date', 'industry'], sort=True).count()
sector_df['max_roc'] = tmp_max_df['roc']
sector_df['min_roc'] = tmp_min_df['roc']
sector_df['count'] = tmp_count_df['roc']
sector_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
sector_df.set_index(['date', 'industry'], inplace=True)
```

The above code works, resulting in a dataframe indexed by date+industry, showing me what was the min/max 'roc' for each date+industry, as well as how many symbols existed for each date+industry.

I am basically doing a complete groupby multiple times (to determine the mean, max, min, count of the 'roc'). This is very slow because it's doing the same thing over and over.

Is there a way to just do the group by once. Then perform the mean, max etc on that object and assign the result to the sector_df?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to perform an aggregate using `agg`:

```
In [72]:

df.groupby(['date','industry']).agg([pd.Series.mean, pd.Series.max, pd.Series.min, pd.Series.count])
Out[72]:
                       roc                
                      mean  max  min count
date       industry                       
2015-02-25 Health    175.0  200  150     2
           Mining     57.5   70   45     2
2015-02-26 Health    185.0  310   60     2
           Mining     44.0   65   23     2
```

This allows you to pass an iterable (a list in this case) of functions to perform.

**EDIT**

To access individual results you need to pass a tuple for each axis:

```
In [78]:
gp.loc[('2015-02-25','Health'),('roc','mean')]

Out[78]:
175.0
```

Where `gp = df.groupby(['date','industry']).agg([pd.Series.mean, pd.Series.max, pd.Series.min, pd.Series.count])`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. How would I refer to a specific value after creating the df, for example how would I get the value for roc mean on 2015-02-25 in Health. I tried the following which didn't work: df.loc['2015-02-25', 'Health']['roc', 'mean']

Comment: @darkpool I've updated my answer to show how to access an individual value

Comment: thanks, im getting a KeyError. Busy trying to figure out why that is happening. Im guessing it is something here that is wrong, not with your answer. I will accept your answer as soon as I can figure out why im getting the KeyError.

Comment: I'd check your index and columns to make sure there isn't a typo, also are your dates datetime dtype or not?

Comment: it's working now thanks. I forgot to reset and then set_index. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the groupby part to a variable as shown below:

```
primary_df = pd.DataFrame([['25-02-2015', 'Health', 'abc', 200],
                   ['25-02-2015', 'Health', 'xyz', 150],
                   ['25-02-2015', 'Mining',  'tyr', 45],
                   ['25-02-2015', 'Mining', 'ujk', 70], 
                   ['26-02-2015', 'Health', 'abc', 60],
                   ['26-02-2015', 'Health', 'xyz', 310],
                   ['26-02-2015', 'Mining',  'tyr', 65],
                   ['26-02-2015', 'Mining', 'ujk', 23]], 
                  columns='date industry symbol roc'.split())

grouped = primary_df.groupby(['date', 'industry'], sort=True)
sector_df = grouped.mean()
tmp_max_df = grouped.max()
tmp_min_df = grouped.min()
tmp_count_df = grouped.count()

sector_df['max_roc'] = tmp_max_df['roc']
sector_df['min_roc'] = tmp_min_df['roc']
sector_df['count'] = tmp_count_df['roc']
sector_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
sector_df.set_index(['date', 'industry'], inplace=True)
```